# fast backtesting library in R

Tags: programming, backtesting

I’m looking for a fast library for backtest in R that supports limit orders, stop-losses, and take-profits. The library should be optimized for repeated historical testing and ideally ported from fast languages such as C++ or Rust. I don’t need complex combinations of trading systems or multi-currency portfolios. I need a backtest for a signal-based trading system with the ability to use not only market but also limit orders, including stop-loss and take-profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [QuantTools](https://quanttools.bitbucket.io/_site/index.html) package. I've never used it, but the backtests are implemented in C++ and the code looks like the person who modeled the orders and events knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

As a first port of call you might try the [Cran Finance Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html) which lists numerous packages relevant to backtesting.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this before and watched it again. What I'm looking for in my question is not there